# how to get the filesize of files in a foreach loop

Tags: php, filesize

I am trying to echo the filesize of all files in a directory but it doesn't echo the filesize, only the filename. This is my code:

```
$dir = "users/$UserName";
$files = scandir($dir);
sort($files);

echo '<table>';
foreach ($files as $file) {
if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') { 
?>

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $file."<br />";
         ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo filesize($file);   
        ?>
    </td>

    </tr>

<?php

}
}
```

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You are passing only file name to filesize function. Give full path like `$dir . '/' . $file`

Comment: Could you give the output html and/or any errors? That would help figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @m_poorUser thanks! now it works: `echo filesize($dir . '/' . $file);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS m_poorUser said you need to pass the full file path to the [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function, maybe if you do this:

```
<?php echo filesize($dir."/".$file); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`scandir` returns **filename** only not **path** to file.

You should use path to file in `filesize($file)`